# Installed openvpn with brew but it doesn't appear to be installed correctly

Tags: macos, homebrew, vpn

I installed `openvpn` with `brew`. The installation went fine, no errors or missing dependencies. But now when I try to run it:

```
users-MBP:~ user$ brew install openvpn
Warning: openvpn-2.3.7 already installed
users-MBP:~ user$ openvpn
-bash: openvpn: command not found
```

I based myself on this tutorial: https://my.hostvpn.com/knowledgebase/29/OpenVPN-on-Mac-OS-X-via-Homebrew-CLI.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you not choose to go with [TunnelBlick](https://tunnelblick.net)?

Comment: @agentroadkill After some time on Linux I have a strong preference for command-line tools over GUIs. Whenever possible I try to go for a CLI solution.

Comment: I believe TunnelBlick is fully configurable from command line, though I rarely use it as I generally use it for simplistic end-user functions.

Comment: @agentroadkill I may look into it. `openvpn` also has the advantage of being the same tool I used on Linux for the job so I could just copy over my configuration files, same commands etc... But I will look into TunnelBlick if I can't get it working.

Comment: TunnelBlick is just an OpenVPN client for MacOS. Any OpenVPN config generated for Linux and/or Windows can be used with it.

Comment: what is the output of which -a openvpn ? - if it's empty then you don't have the path where openvpn is installed inside your $PATH Environment Variable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At the terminal type:

```
echo $PATH
```

That's your default search path for executables.  Looks like the openvpn executable was installed someplace not in your search path.

First, you'll need to find the openvpn executable:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "openvpn"
```

Then add the directory containing the openvpn executable to your default search path by adding this sort of line to the end of your .profile (in your home directory, a.k.a. /Users/yourusername/.profile:

```
export PATH="/some/brew/dir:$PATH"
```

Comment: `brew info openvpn` is faster

Comment: Try using `sudo openvpn` before going with this answer. It seems silly, but I was going through this answer when I found openvpn is installed in the `usr/sbin` folder - which means that you can't execute openvpn or anything else in that folder without sudo - and you will get `openvpn: command not found` without using sudo. Or you can login as root, but that's just unnecessary. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Years later, the DMG/PKG installer from https://openvpn.net/vpn-client/ no longer seems to contain a command-line client.

Answer (score 69):

Add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$(brew --prefix openvpn)/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: You won my heart

Comment: Works for Apple silicon versions as well.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly on 12.6 Intel as well

Answer (score 17):

In my case:

1. Installation using homebrew

> `brew install openvpn`

2. Information regarding binaries

> `brew info openvpn`

3. It gave me installation path as:

> `/usr/local/Cellar/openvpn/2.4.0`

4. Then I browsed for `bin` directory but found executable inside `sbin`. So, I added following line

> `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/openvpn/2.4.0/sbin`

in my `~/.zshrc` file
as well as in `~/.bash_profile` file using a text editor.

Worked Flawlessly,
After a workaround for an hour :)

Answer (score 11):

You have to add `/usr/local/sbin` to your path.

It was installed to `/usr/local/sbin` but that directory is not in your `$PATH` by default. Add a line like this to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: This is the best fix, but the best, permanent way to make the fix it is to edit `/etc/paths` and add `/usr/local/sbin` to it (more info [here](https://serverfault.com/q/16355/))

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue today and I had to do `sudo brew services start openvpn`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a symlink from usr/local/sbin into usr/local/bin like so:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s ../sbin/openvpn .
```

Answer (score 1):

Brew now link the openvpn binary.
reinstall it using

```
brew reinstall openvpn
```